# Material icon fonts are not working due to IE's font download security option disabled

Tags: icon-fonts, google-material-icons, ligature

Here is the scenario,

The application uses already developed APIs such kendo-ui and few more internal developed APIs for UI component with AgnularJS.
In these liberaries and in our application we have followed "npm dependency" approach for material icon and hosted them with the deployed build.

However at this point of time we found that there are the situations and scenarios, where end user have the security concerns and the applied policy of the system doesn't allow to change the IE's configurations such as :
**

> IE >> Internet Options >> Security tab >> Internet >> custom level >>
>   font download option as disabled.

**

However, we can not enforce the end user to modify the security configurations and even they won't be able to do so.

Hence I am looking for alternative approach. because replacing every icon font with icon images will be an extremely complex and tedious.

> What I already have followed is:
>
> 1. Adding domain to trusted domain -  yes it works but end user can not modify any settings. So this is not useful.
> 2. Self hosted icon fonts - Not working
> 3. URL to refer google's api repository - not working
> 4. Changing the security configurations - not allowed

Hence looking for any alternate solution, if anyone have faced similar scenarios in past.

Any pointers will be really a great help for this issue.

Thank you,

Comment: The internet policy must be updated so that the fonts can be downloaded at least from the same domain.